# Search and replace inserting character

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I have a project with PhpStorm and I need to find and replace all instances of `@include('[not a forward slash]` and add a forward slash (`/`) after the single quote.

For example: find all `@include('a` and replace with `@include('/a`. Only I would prefer not to do this 26 times for each letter of the alphabet.

How would I do this with PhpStorm?

I can find in path using regex `@include\('\w`, but there are hundreds and it is very slow doing this manually.

Comment: What is your current problem? since this `@include\('\w` is the right regex.

Comment: That finds it, i'm looking for how to replace it by inserting the forward slash.

Comment: Try to find `(@include\(')(\w)` and replace with `$1/$2`. If replacement didn't take place correctly use `\1/\2` instead.

Comment: You probably want the preg_replace function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In latest PhpStorm use **Replace in Path** (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>):

- regex pattern to find: `@include\(\'(?!/)`
- regex pattern to replace: `@include\(\'\/`